# Spring Boot + React + Keycloak after login returns No Access-Controll-Allow-Origin header is present

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors, keycloak

I am trying to add a frontend to my SpringBoot application. I also have a users provider connected perfectly, because if I did a CURL it works.

```
The problem begins when connecting react to Keycloak to do a login, it shows the login page, but when the login is OK it returns
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:18080/auth/realms/Realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

It still problem of Keycloak because it is working by CURL, but I could not reach to configure it well.

I add a * in Web Origins of the Client also.

Answer (score 0):

You won't reproduce [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem with `curl` cause it is browser conventions.

Basically, the browser considers a request as a CORS when a client request contains:

```
headers:
    Origin: 127.0.0.1
    Set-Fetch-Mode: cors
```

And server response must contain: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` where * can be changed for specific resources.

See article about CORS and `@CrossOrigin` annotation inside Spring

Comment: But the error comes from keycloak, because I also tried to delete the connection with the backend and also happens...

Comment: This means that keycloak library executes HTTP request as I said with `cors`. You have to modify your localhost server, in this case, to allow a required origin

Comment: I found that my client was confidential and that's the problem. If I change the client to public the exception does not occur more.